# powerpoint variables

Tags: variables, powerpoint

Im a teacher and I write point-and-click games in powerpoint.
I have a slide with 3 buttons and code with 2 variables (`var1` and `var2`)
button 3 is the exit (escape) button and will only work if `var1 = 1` and `var2 = 1`
the buttons must be pushed in the correct order to escape (button 1 followed by button 2)
i have declared the variables as integers at the top of the module.
my code is as follows...

```
sub button1()
var1 = 1
var2 = 0
end sub

sub button2()
var2 = 1
end sub

sub button exit()
If var1.Value = 1 & var2.Value = 1 Then
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide 58, msoFalse
End With
Else
MsgBox ("incorrect combination")
End If
end sub
```

I'm not an expert and cannot figure out why this will not work.
Any help please.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to check out [App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/teach/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  If not, let let us know what goes wrong:

```
Option Explicit
' Always start with this; it forces you to 
' declare your variables properly

Dim var1 as integer
Dim var2 as integer

sub button1()
var1 = 1
var2 = 0
end sub

sub button2()
var2 = 1
end sub

sub button exit()
If var1 + var2 = 2 Then
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide 58, msoFalse
End With
Else
MsgBox ("incorrect combination")
End If
end sub
```

Comment: Steve, this worked perfectly and I have now expanded the code to include more buttons for combination locks and puzzles.  Thank you so much for your help I am very grateful.

Comment: Great ... glad to hear it.  You might also want to have a look at my friend Glenna Shaw's site:  http://www.pptmagic.com/